Permit2 Invalid Nonce when running on Hardhat
I'm writing tests for an application that is meant to perform swaps. When running with hardhat as rpc forked with the latest block of mainnet or a pinned block I always encounter this error:
response = {'error': {'code': -32603, 'data': {'data': '0x815e1d64', 'message': 'Error: VM Exception while processing transaction...essing transaction: reverted with an unrecognized custom error (return data: 0x815e1d64)'}, 'id': 49, 'jsonrpc': '2.0'}

which seems to reflect permit2's error for InvalidNonce.
Running this on mainnet won't raise the error at all.

Apparently setting a fixed chain id solves it.
Using the following config made the trick:
module.exports = {
  solidity: "0.8.17",
  networks: {
    hardhat: {
      forking: {
        url: "RPC", 
      },
      chainId: 1, 
    },
  },
  mocha: {
    timeout: 20000,
  },
};

Removing the chainId will raise the same issue as before.
